# How to add default values for Thymeleaf input fields?

Tags: thymeleaf

Here is my thymeleaf form input field. I want to set a default value for that. Suppose I want set "individual" as default value. how to do that?

```
 <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('priceSearchDTO.partyType')}" th:errors="*{priceSearchDTO.partyType}"
                                   class="validation-message"></label>
                            <input type="text" th:field="*{priceSearchDTO.partyType}" placeholder="partyType"
                                   class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
```

Additionally I tried with this, But it doesn't work as normal html field.

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
                        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('priceSearchDTO.partyType')}" th:errors="*{priceSearchDTO.partyType}"
                               class="validation-message"></label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{priceSearchDTO.partyType}" placeholder="partyType" value="individual"
                               class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a th:placeholder attribute. You can use this attribute to set the value of the placeholder attribute dynamically, e.g.:

```
<input ...  th:placeholder="${#object.individualPlaceholder}" ...>
```

or

```
<input ...  th:placeholder="|Static and ${#object.dynamic}|" ...>
```

If your placeholder is a static value, you can still use the placeholder-attribute:

```
<input ...  placeholder="Insert something" ...>
```

It's also possible use a static value for th:placeholder.